# How do I get a broadcast for USB Storage Device and access it on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-storage

I'm making an application to browse data in a card reader and perform some operations on the data in it. But the **MEDIA_MOUNTED** intent in Android doesn't seem to fire up when I connect an external device.

The broadcast receiver that I set up is as follows. However, it never receives the broadcasts.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MediaReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have tried running this application on Samsung, MI, and OnePlus phones as of now along with an Android One phone. These devices just don't send the broadcast. I tried a Moto G phone and this was working just fine on it.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Note:
I tried logging the broadcasts that the Operating System sends when I connect and there is no **Media_Mounted, Media_Unmounted**, or related Broadcast among them. I only get **USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED** and **USB_DEVICE_DETACHED** broadcasts.

Comment: can you show the Broadcast receiver class

Comment: The code for BroadcastReceiver Class:
```
class MediaReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val action = intent!!.action
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: $action")
    }
}
```
@ArvinRezaei